# How can you transform text to latex using mathJax included in JSXgraph?

Tags: javascript, math, mathjax, jsxgraph

I'm trying to render an equation using mathJax that comes with the JSXgraph 0.99.7.

Simple forms seem to render (r^2=(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2), but not functions or fractions (1=\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}).

Here is an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqago.jpg)

Current code to draw an ellipse:

```
var graph = board.create('ellipse', [A, B, C], {
        id: field,
        fixed: true,
        useMathJax: true,
        withLabel: true,
        name: '',
        strokeColor: color,
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fillColor: shade,
        fillOpacity: 0.3,
        size: 2,
        dash: dashed,
        highlightStrokeColor: 'red',
        highlightStrokeWidth: 3,
        highlightFillColor: shade,
        highlightFillOpacity: op
    });
    graph.on('down', function (e, i) {
        showMaster(this.id); 
        graph.setName('1=\\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}');
    });
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, labels are not parsed for MathJax content. The necessary change is to add

```
   label: {useMathJax: true, visible: false}
```

to the ellipse declaration.
Additionally, I would like to suggest to set the name when creating the ellipse and just set the label to visible on the `down` event.

Here is the full example:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js"],
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
    },
    "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
  });

var A = board.create('point', [-2, 0]);
var B = board.create('point', [1, 0]);
var C = board.create('point', [0, 2]);

var graph = board.create('ellipse', [A, B, C], {
    withLabel: true,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
    fillColor: '#cccccc',
    fillOpacity: 0.3,
    highlightStrokeColor: 'red',
    highlightStrokeWidth: 3,
    name: '$1=\\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}$',
    label: {useMathJax: true, visible: false}
});
graph.on('down', function (e, i) {
    graph.label.setAttribute({visible: true});
});
```

See it live at http://jsfiddle.net/r3fxcp54/1/